# ROS Accessing Webcam

Tags: ros

I m learning ROS (Beginner) and i m trying to access my webcam

I m trying to use cv_camera module here

http://wiki.ros.org/cv_camera

THis line works fine

```
rosparam set cv_camera/device_id 0
```

But i m getting following error on this line

```
rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rospack] Error: package 'cv_camera' not found
```

Am i supposed to install something or missing something?

Here is my struggle as terminal output (may be helpful)

```
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosparam set cv_camera/device_id 1
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rospack] Error: package 'cv_camera' not found
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/huzeyfe/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rospack] Error: package 'cv_camera' not found
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosparam set cv_camera/device_id 1
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rospack] Error: package 'cv_camera' not found
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.018304 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.016891   /opt/ros/kinetic/share
0.000488 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev
0.000077 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/haarcascades
0.000056 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/lbpcascades
0.000042 * /home/huzeyfe/catkin_ws/src
0.000038 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc
0.000007 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rospack] Error: package 'cv_camera' not found
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/huzeyfe/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
huzeyfe@huzeyfe-Aspire-5755G:~/catkin_ws$
```

Comment: Looks like the package is not installed yet. Try to install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-camera`

Comment: To install package in ROS it is always similar: `sudo apt-get install ros-distribution-name_of_the_package`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install the `cv-camera` package. Since you are using ROS kinetic (and presumably Ubuntu 16.04), you have to install it with the following line:

```
apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-camera
```

Here is also a good post about installing packages: [LINK](https://answers.ros.org/question/9201/how-do-i-install-a-missing-ros-package/).
You can also dig into the debug messages of rosrun by using the `--debug` flag. In my terminal, it tells me then:

```
bash> rosrun --debug cv_camera cv_camera_node
[rosrun] Looking in catkin libexec dirs: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cv_camera
[rosrun] Looking in rospack dir: /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cv_camera
[rosrun]   2
[rosrun] Searching for cv_camera_node with permissions /111
[rosrun]   2
[rosrun] Running  /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cv_camera/cv_camera_node
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-uvc-camera
rospack list
rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node
rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view
```

Try those line. Should help you see the camera stream directly
rospack is need if system cant find uvc_camera initially.